# How to add number with trailing zero in JSON(php)

Tags: php, json

I have an array, which contains some prices data.

```
$products[] = array(               
               'price' => number_format((float)$row['price'], 1, '.', '')
)
```

And then I making JSON file with this array:

```
 fwrite($fp, json_encode($products, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE | JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES));
```

The problem is that in JSON the price is a string:

```
 "price": "4750.0",
```

And I need to keep it as a number (with trailing zero!):

```
 "price": 4750.0,
```

I've tried to convert price to float:

```
$products[] = array(               
               'price' => (float)number_format((float)$row['price'], 1, '.', '')
)
```

And it helps with convert string to number in JSON, but it cuts my trailing zero:

```
  "price": 4750,
```

Comment: If you want to keep it as a number, then I don't think you can. The encoder will treat `4750.0` as equal to `4750`.

Comment: `4750` is mathematically identical to `4750.0` so, when expressing this as a number (not a string) there is no need to keep the trailing .0. It's not really clear why you see this as a problem. Why do you "need" to keep the .0, exactly?

Comment: @ADyson Just trying to make my JSON the same as in schema: https://api-docs.glovoapp.com/partners/index.html#json-schema The example is:  "id": "id-7",
      "name": "Half/half pizza Small",
      "price": "11.0",

Comment: Whoever wrote that specification doesn't understand JSON, or maths.

Comment: And is pretty inconsistent. In some places it's a number `"price_impact": 0.0` while in others it's a string `"price_impact": "4.0"`. Encode as a string and be on your merry way.

Comment: Anyway, any standard library which tries to decode your JSON will be perfectly fine without the trailing .0, as it's redundant. You should not need to match the schema's number formatting. You could also try El_vanja's suggestion to keep them all as strings, but I'm less certain that it would then pass any kind of type-checking validation imposed by the code which deals with the decoded data. It really depends where you're sending the JSON once you've created it, and how it will be processed. Are you planning to send it to that API? I suggest testing how it reacts to what json_encode produces.

Comment: @ADyson No, I'm planning to public it on my web site and then send POST request to API with URL to JSON file inside. Ok, I think I got your point. Thank you!